# Solution Explorer is not showing in Microsoft Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

The solution explorer is not showing.[I have tried to go into tools>options>Project and solutions>General.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1qFW.png) But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Open Solution Explorer from **View > Solution Explorer** or use the shortcut Ctrl + Alt + L

Answer (score 0):

In **Visual Studio 2022** you can simply use Ctrl+ Tab and it shows navigation to your tabs and also solution explorer and more.